# How can I Always show Status and Navigation Bar in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

first of all, I used google translate because my English is insufficient, sorry for the mistakes.

I want Status and Navigation Bar to be always open in my Unity project. How can I do that? I found some things on the internet but I don't fully understand.
https://zehfernando.com/2015/unity-tidbits-changing-the-visibility-of-androids-navigation-and-status-bars-and-implementing-immersive-mode/

I found 1 asset, but unfortunately I am not in a position to buy it.
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/status-navigation-bar-221190